# Restoration of TWRP full system backup fails due to /data format

Tags: backup, twrp, restore, 8.0-oreo

**Device**: Samsung Galaxy A3 (2017), a.k.a.: SM-A320Y

**OS**: Android 8

**TWRP**: 3.6.2-9

I created backups of the following partitions:

- Boot
- System
- System Image

When restoring either of them, I get the infamous error:

`Failed to mount '/data' (Invalid argument)`

I can make this error temporarily go away by:

1. Reformatting `/data` as FAT or exFAT and
2. then back to ext4

When re-restoring either of the partitions afterwards, TWRP reports success, but the phone ends up in the boot-loop.

Side note: when attempting to repair the `/data` partition, before the 2 steps above, the error message is:

```
/sbin/e2fsck -fp /dev/block/mmcblk0p24 process ended with ERROR: 8
Unable to repair Data.
```

Search results for error 8 of e2fsck are not really encouraging though...

Is there any possibility to

- either restore the backup
- or read the data in the backup differently?

Thank you very much already.

P.S. I'm aware that there is a truck load full of questions like this on the internet, but I couldn't find an answer sadly :-(